# Angular images 404

Tags: angular, image, directory, http-status-code-404

I have been having problems showing an image which is stored within the assets folder in a library of the project, I have several images in this folder, only one of them is displayed, all the others (the ones I need to place on the HTML will not show ) I have tried with all kinds of relative and absolute path and it still returns as 404:

Angular.json:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "projects": {
    "admin": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "apps/admin",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/admin/src",
      "prefix": "eshop-frontend",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/admin",
            "index": "apps/admin/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/admin/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/admin/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/admin/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["apps/admin/src/favicon.ico", "apps/admin/src/assets"],
            "styles": ["apps/admin/src/styles.scss",
            "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
            "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "admin:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "admin:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "admin:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "apps/admin/src/**/*.ts",
              "apps/admin/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/admin"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/admin/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": []
    },
    "admin-e2e": {
      "root": "apps/admin-e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/admin-e2e/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
          "options": {
            "cypressConfig": "apps/admin-e2e/cypress.json",
            "devServerTarget": "admin:serve:development"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "admin:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/admin-e2e/**/*.{js,ts}"]
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": [],
      "implicitDependencies": ["admin"]
    },
    "cataldo-store": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "root": "apps/cataldo-store",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/cataldo-store/src",
      "prefix": "eshop-frontend",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/cataldo-store",
            "index": "apps/cataldo-store/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/cataldo-store/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/cataldo-store/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/cataldo-store/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "apps/cataldo-store/src/favicon.ico",
              "apps/cataldo-store/src/assets"

            ],
            "styles": ["apps/cataldo-store/src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/cataldo-store/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/cataldo-store/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "cataldo-store:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "cataldo-store:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cataldo-store:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "apps/cataldo-store/src/**/*.ts",
              "apps/cataldo-store/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/cataldo-store"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/cataldo-store/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": []
    },
    "cataldo-store-e2e": {
      "root": "apps/cataldo-store-e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/cataldo-store-e2e/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
          "options": {
            "cypressConfig": "apps/cataldo-store-e2e/cypress.json",
            "devServerTarget": "cataldo-store:serve:development"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "cataldo-store:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/cataldo-store-e2e/**/*.{js,ts}"]
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": [],
      "implicitDependencies": ["cataldo-store"]
    },
    "orders": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/orders",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/orders/src",
      "prefix": "orders",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/angular:ng-packagr-lite",
          "outputs": ["dist/libs/orders"],
          "options": {
            "project": "libs/orders/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "libs/orders/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "libs/orders/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/orders"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/orders/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "libs/orders/src/**/*.ts",
              "libs/orders/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": []
    },
    "products": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/products",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/products/src",
      "prefix": "eshop-frontend",
      "architect": {
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/products"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/products/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "libs/products/src/**/*.ts",
              "libs/products/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": []
    },
    "ui": {
      "root": "libs/ui",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/ui/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "assets":"libs/ui/src/lib/assets",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/ui/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/ui"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/ui/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        } 
      },
      "tags": []
    },
    "users": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/users",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/users/src",
      "prefix": "users",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/angular:ng-packagr-lite",
          "outputs": ["dist/libs/users"],
          "options": {
            "project": "libs/users/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "libs/users/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "libs/users/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/users"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/users/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "libs/users/src/**/*.ts",
              "libs/users/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": []
    }
  }
}
```

The following is the folder structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmCo1.png)

all I was trying to do is having an image within the slider component, it seems it will not work in any way, if I try to have the image as background it does work...
any idea ?

edit: image loaded:

```
 <img src="../assets/banner-image.svg" alt="">
```

image not loaded:

```
  <img src="../assets/barbour.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Please share at least a code that successfully loads an image, and one that fails to do so.

Comment: the correct is `src="assets/barbour.png"`. Angular put a copy of your folder assets in a subfolder assets. Really take account the `href` -if you use i18n to multidioms, e.g. you has two folders inside the dist, e.g. es-ES and en-US  and inside each one an assets folder

Comment: Hey, I just tried that, nothing works, nothing  online to solve this and as usual nothing on stackoverflow.